# how to add site_id or host to django debug log?

Tags: python, django, logging

I've made a multisite app that sets django SITE_ID setting in middleware like this:

```
host = request.get_host()
site = Site.objects.get(domain=host)
settings.SITE_ID = site.id
```

everything works fine, but django debug logs produce strings like:

```
2014-08-12 16:13:32,484 WARNING base: Not Found: /href
```

that is good, but I really need to know what site/host they come from, what is a good way to do it?

my current logging settings:

```
    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'formatters': {
            'verbose': {
                'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(module)s: %(message)s',
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            'file': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
                'filename': 'django.debug.log',
                'formatter': 'verbose',
            },
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django.request': {
                'handlers': ['file'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': True,
            },
        },
    }
```

Comment: Add your own logger handler and log freely yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `logging.Filter` as described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information) in the logging documentation. The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#examples) includes information on configuring logging, including filters.

Answer (score 3):

Did it this way:

logging_filters.py:

```
import logging
from django.conf import settings


class SiteFilter(logging.Filter):

    def filter(self, record):

        record.site = settings.SITE_ID  # set dynamically in middleware.py
        return True
```

settings.py: (project.settings)

```
    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'filters': {  # !
            'site_filter': {
                '()': 'project.logging_filters.SiteFilter',
            }
        },
        'formatters': {
            'verbose': {  # %(site)s - from filter
                'format': '%(asctime)s %(site)s %(levelname)s %(module)s: %(message)s',
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            'file': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
                'filename': 'example.com.django.debug.log',
                'filters': ['site_filter'],  # !
                'formatter': 'verbose',
            },
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django.request': {
                'handlers': ['file'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': True,
                'filters': ['site_filter'],  # !
            },
        },
    }
```